# Cannot resize flaticon with font-size

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I am using Flaticon for a website I am developing but there seems to something wrong and I can't find out what.

I downloaded the zip file from flaticon with the option "icon font".
so I uploaded it into the my font's folder but for some reason when I link the css and put an `<i class="flaticon-crowd"><i>` in my html I get the icon in its default size but when I put `font-size:70px;` in the css it doesn't get bigger.

I can do `color: #f00;` and the text turns red so it's not the selector.
Also in the def tools in chrome show that the 70px font-size is used and not overruled.

Does somebody know what it could be that is causing this problem ?

thanks for your time.

Here is an example of the html I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- flaticon -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/flaticon/flaticon.css">

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <i style="font-size: 70px" class="flaticon flaticon-crowd"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @paulie I have seen examples that do use font-size but I also tried using size and height but it didn't affect the icon in any way. Also there is no way to recreate this. it is build into the page and it just happend.
I do begin to think it might me clashing with something ielse.

Comment: I just added the code example. in that situation it doesn't work.
also as state in the OP I downloaded the fonticon zip.
Also followed the instructions of how to add them to the page.
On other websites it is used with font-size so as I downloaded it as fonticon I assume that it is seen as font and not as something else

Comment: OK...do you have any CSS...such as the `@font-face`  statement to load the font. Heck, do you hava link to a live page we can look at...perhaps that would be simpler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this class in your css to change the font size.

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before, [class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {

font-size: 150px;

}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Good point and just tried but did not work.
there are some websites that I know use it to and they use font-size to.
So it 'should' work but I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: I have changed the answer. this one i checked. its works in my side.

Comment: it worked like a charm.
It's pretty weird that it doesn't work with normal classes and font-sizing

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12):

A better solution would be:

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {

font-size: 1em;

}
```

Then the size of the icon can be modified by other classes using font-size

Comment: Make sure your stylesheet is imported after the flaticon one.

Comment: that's the better solution because it enables you to use the icons in different sizes (and not just 150px as mentioned above)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Just change the default font size to 1em in the flaticon.css file.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
.flaticon-fast46::before{
font-size: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the pseudo class :before to modify the icon as you want. You can apply all text properties of css to modify the icons.

```
.flaticon-crowd:before {
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the 'font-size: 20px;' found in the flaticon.css file and then you will be able to set the size you want in your css file.

Comment: This works. A betters solution would be to set it to auto using a second stylesheet with higher precedence so you can continue to copy theirs in if you edit it

Answer (score 1):

It's Worked For me. Add `:before` after the element class which you want to use for icons.

```
span:before{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for sure you could add `!important` to your css  declaration

**For example:**

```
font-size:100px !important;
```

Comment: thing is that it is not being overridden. But I did try using the !important but sadly did nothing.

Comment: I am but they don't have some of the icon that I need. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In flaticons.css change the default class into this:

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
    font-family: "Flaticon" !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-variant: normal !important;
    text-transform: none !important;
    speak: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the flaticon.css file contains a line that specifies the 
    font-size: 20px;
this applies over all the flat icons. You may delete that entry to freely edit single icons, or you can respecify a preferred icon size in that same line which will be reflected in all the icons.